# Pattern for hiding recursive function in Scala

Tags: scala, design-patterns, functional-programming

Given this recursive function :

```
 def visitAll(s: String): Unit = {
    val files = getFiles
    for (a <- files) {
      visitAll(s)
      doSomeWork()
    }
  }
```

This will act as a driver for work. Is there a pattern or Scala idiom that will allow to hide recursive structure from developer so all all developer needs to worry about is implementing method `doSomeWork()` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply pass in a function (i.e. `doSomeWork`) as follows:

```
  def visitAll(s: String, f: () => Any): Unit = {
    val files = getFiles
    for (a <- files) {
      visitAll(s, f)
      f()
    }
  }
```

Then call it like so:

```
visitAll("foo", doSomeWork)
```

The function is handed down the recursive calls, and executed where required.

Another pattern is to provide a curried call-by-name parameter rather than a function:

```
  def visitAll(s: String)(f: => Any): Unit = {
    val files = getFiles
    for (a <- files) {
      visitAll(s)(f)
      f
    }
  }
```

Then you can call this with a code block, e.g.

```
visitAll("foo") {
   println("doing some work")
}
```

as well as passing a function:

```
visitAll("foo")(doSomething)
```

Yet another approach would be to create a Stream or Iterator of files, then call `doSomeWork` by passing it to the `map` or `foreach` methods of the Stream - though this would need more changes to your code.